# Accessing certain Ziost areas

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Once you complete the Ziost story line you are left with this gray area of doom and a few dailies but no clear way to see the rest of Ziost ever again.

As the gray area is boring me and I am missing one walker for the achievement, I would like to go back the the pre-doom Ziost.

Is there any way to do this with my current character? I only have 2 characters past level 55 and one is just for PvP, so building up a new character to the Ziost storyline would take effort for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A groupmate with a guild ship and summoning permissions can summon you to their location (for 20k credits), so someone on the pre-doom area of Ziost could do this for you.  There isn't any built-in way to get there on your own, since it's intended to be the same location — just after-the-fact.